# Accessing environment variables from client side app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, dotenv

I want to access environment variables from my .env file, located in the root directory, and use them in my App.js React file using dotenv. However, I am not able to access them. on the client side (App.js).

#### File Structure:

The variables I want to use: **root/.env**
The file I want to use them in: **root/client/src/App.js**

#### .env file:

```
PORT=5432  
TEST=911  
REACT_APP_WEATHER=12345678
```

#### App.js file

```
import './App.css';
require("dotenv").config();

// Doesn't show the variables in the .env file
console.log(process.env);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I read that dotenv (which is installed in my root directory) doesn't work on client-side and only on server-side [Using environment variables in React](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5). Do I need to install that webpack? I tried installing it in my client but it created many errors.

**Note: I want to store my server and client environment variables in the same .env file**

Comment: There is no `process` on the client and neither are there environment variables. If you want to transport values from the server to the client, do it the usual way.

Comment: You don't use `dotenv` on the client side. Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: @Jayce444 yeah I used `npx create-react-app client` to make the client folder. So how would I access those variables

Comment: @Bergi I was following the React documentation to access environment variables such as process.env.NODE_ENV

Answer (score 1):

With `create-react-app` you don't have to use `dotenv` library of anything like that. To read from `.env` file all you have to do is prefix all the variables name with `REACT_APP_`. For example:

```
REACT_APP_PORT=5432  
REACT_APP_TEST=911  
REACT_APP_WEATHER=12345678
```

`create-react-app` will automatically make it available to you during the build time. On your react app, from anywhere, you can `console.log` this:

```js
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_PORT); //5432
```