# Env vars only partially loading

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, dotenv

In my React app, I use the `dotenv` and `dotenv-expand` modules with `webpack` to manage my environment variables locally.
At the top of my start script I have:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";
require("../src/config/env");
```

This points to `/src/config/env.js`, which includes:

```
const paths = require("./paths");
var dotenvFiles = [
    `${paths.dotenv}.${NODE_ENV}.local`,
    `${paths.dotenv}.${NODE_ENV}`,
    NODE_ENV !== "test" && `${paths.dotenv}.local`,
    paths.dotenv,
].filter(Boolean);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dotenvFiles));
// The above line confirms the .env file is included in dotenvFiles

var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand');
dotenvFiles.forEach((dotenvFile) => {
    if (fs.existsSync(dotenvFile)) {
        var myEnv = dotenv.config({
            path: dotenvFile,
        });
        dotenvExpand.expand(myEnv);
    }
});
console.log(process.env.HIRING);
// The above line returns the correct value. At this point, it seems to have correctly loaded in the env vars.
```

In my `.env` file I have the content below. All variables have a value, which I just removed here in this post:

```
CLIENT_PORT=
API_URL=
APP_URL=
RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=
ANALYTICS_TAG=
DURATION=
HIRING=
```

Then on a React page I have:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env));
```

This last line returns:

```
{
    "NODE_ENV":"development",
    "PUBLIC_URL":"",
    "API_URL":"http://localhost:3000/api/",
    "RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY":"xxx",
    "APP_URL":"http://localhost:3002"
}
// Now HIRING no longer seems to be there...
```

Although this includes 3 variables that are in the `.env` file (these are not defined anywhere else), other variables from the `.env` file **are missing** here (even though the `console.log` line at the end of  `/src/config/env.js` included for example `HIRING` which at this points is missing from the env vars. What could be the cause of this? How can I ensure all the env vars are available on the React page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side, you HAVE to start the name of an environment variable with `REACT_APP_`. For example, changing the env var name `HIRING` to `REACT_APP_HIRING` made it work.

Found this solution via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64654842), which links to [here](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5).